# search, edit and delete using gridview with sql server in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

i am using Gridview buttons to edit and delet records from sql DB , the problem that i use specific criteris (search by textbox and combobox) then i do edit for the results here is the code i use :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["zamzammembersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
     bind();

    }
    }

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bind();

}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

    bind();

}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("lblid");
    TextBox textname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("textbox1");
    TextBox textmarks = (TextBox)row.FindControl("textbox2");
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update  emp set marks=" + textmarks.Text + " , name='" + textname.Text + "' where rowid=" + lbl.Text + "", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    bind();

}
public void bind()
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select zam_pcinfo.employe_name as Name , zam_location.locationname as Location from zam_pcinfo  inner join zam_location on zam_pcinfo.location_id = zam_location.locationId where zam_pcinfo.employe_name like @name or zam_location.locationname like @locationname;", conn);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nametxt.Text;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = locationdrop.SelectedValue;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{

}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Label lbldeleteID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblid");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete  emp where rowid=" + lbldeleteID.Text + "", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    bind();
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    bind();

}
```

}

when i try to make the same code in `bind()` method to a button it works fine but i couldn't do edit and delete on it . how can i make edit and delete in `gridview` with data that i search for ?